# Node.js post video from s3 to Facebook via Graph API

Tags: node.js, facebook-graph-api, amazon-s3

I have a video file on s3 that I want to post to a user Facebook account:

```
https.get(signedUrlOfObjectInS3, function(httpRes){

    var form = new formData(); // that's form-data module https://github.com/felixge/node-form-data
    form.append('source', httpRes); 

    var options = {
        method: 'post',
        host: 'graph-video.facebook.com',
        path: '/me/videos?access_token=' + user_access_token,
        headers: form.getHeaders(),
    }

    var buffer = '';
    var apiCall = https.request(options, function (res){
        res.on('data',function(chunk){
            buffer += chunk; 
        });

        res.on('end',function(){
            var data = JSON.parse(buffer);
            console.log('data from fb is: ' + util.inspect(data));
        });
    });

    form.pipe(apiCall);

});
```

The response I get from Facebook is:

> (#352) Sorry, the video file you selected is in a format that we don\'t support.

The video file on s3 is a mov file with a content type of video/quicktime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, so apparently Facebook ignores the content type in the headers and guesses it from the file name. Since the s3 signed url doesn't end with filename.mov for example, it doesn't get it...

All I had to do was concating a '&f=filename.mov' to the end of the signedUrl, and now Facebook get that...

Answer (score 0):

The following code actually worked fine for me for me:

```js
https.get(signedUrlOfObjectInS3, function(httpRes) {
    var form = new FormData(); // that's form-data module https://github.com/felixge/node-form-data
    form.append('source', httpRes);
    var options = {
        method: 'post',
        host: 'graph-video.facebook.com',
        path: '/me/videos?access_token=' + user_access_token,
        headers: form.getHeaders(),
    }

    var apiCall = https.request(options);

    form.pipe(apiCall);

    apiCall.on('response', function(res) {

        console.log(res.statusCode);
    });

});
```

try making the small difference in apiCall postback ,

other explanation might be that i've used a public amazon URL...

Comment: The other explanation surprisingly seems to have made the trick. I tested your code and it didn't work at first either. Then I pasted the public url of that s3 object into the code and override signedUrlOfObjectInS3, and it magically worked! Question is: what do I do now? My s3 object should remain private, I made it public only for this test. What's the difference between the stream of signed url and the stream of public object in s3? by the way I compared the http headers and they're quite the same (content type and content length)